# How to stub exported function from module in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, sinon, stub

I'm not able to see stubbed response for `getName` method while invoking `getUser` from Cypress. Is there a way to correct this?

```
// Service.ts    
export const getName = (): string => {
    return name;
}

// User.ts
import {getName} from './Service'
export const getUser = (): User => {
    const name = getName();
    // ... rest of code for User creation 
}

// User.cypress.ts
import * as service from './Service'
it('tests user', () => {
    cy.stub(service, 'getName').returns('abc');
    cy.get('#get-user-id').click(); 
});
```

Comment: Insufficient information given to answer. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the way the function is exported from `Service.ts`.

Try adding a default export to the module.

```js
// Service.ts    
const getName = (): string => {
    return name;
}

module.exports {
  getName
}
```

```js
// User.cypress.ts
import service from './Service'

it('tests user', () => {
    cy.stub(service, 'getName').returns('abc');
    cy.get('#get-user-id').click(); 
});
```

Comment: It didn't work form me. Did it for you?